# Jackson FasterXML : How does Spring know how to json object?

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I am currently following this [tutorial](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-rest-service-example-using-restcontroller/) about Spring MVC and REST service. It is a simple hello world project.

There is something I don't understand. In the pom.xml we set jackson dependency but it is never configurated. How does Spring know how to json object ?

Here is samples of code :

**pom xml (dependencies) :**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**AppConfiguration :**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "package.to.scan")
public class AppConfiguration {
}
```

**AppInitializer :**

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

**AppController :**

```
@RestController
public class AppController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome to RestTemplate Example.";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{player}")
    public Message message(@PathVariable String player) {

        Message msg = new Message(player, "Hello " + player);
        return msg;
    }
}
```

**Model :**

```
public class Message {

    String name;
    String text;

    public Message(){

    }

    public Message(String name, String text) {
        this.name = name;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring has a default set of `HttpMessageConverter`s, one of them being `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, which is used if the content type is json and if Jackson is available in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes my day.